# Ruby on Rails importing bootstrap not found

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap

**Second Edit**
Thanks for all the helpful guidance, I was able to fix the error by rolling back my version of ruby. I had to make several other tweaks, but that was the main one, especially considering that I was following a tutorial.

**Edit**
I am still unsuccessful after making the changes cjn suggested. I am getting this error:

```
 Static pages Home page should have the content 'Sample App'
 Failure/Error: visit '/static_pages/home'
 ActionView::Template::Error:
   couldn't find file 'jquery'
     (in /Users/me/rails_projects/sample_app/app/assets/javascripts/application.js:13)
 # ./app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:7:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb__1639650066512045899_2207712920'
 # ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:8:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

**----original post----**

I am a novice in programming RoR. Currently I am going through the Michael Hartl, "Ruby on Rails Tutorial". I have been stuck on this problem for the past day or so.

In apps/assets/stylesheets I have a file called custom.css.scss. In this file i have one line:

```
@import "bootstrap";
```

however I am getting an error:

```
 Failure/Error: visit '/static_pages/about'
 ActionView::Template::Error:
   File to import not found or unreadable: bootstrap.
   Load paths:

     /Users/me/rails_projects/sample_app
     /Users/me/rails_projects/vendor/assets/stylesheets
     (in /Users/me/rails_projects/sample_app/app/assets/stylesheets/application.css)
 # (sass):15
 # ./app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:5:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb__2871330256659661911_2185769240'
 # ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:39:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

In my Gemfile I have:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.1.0'
#ruby-gemset=railstutorial_rails_4_0

gem 'rails', '4.0.5'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '2.3.0.1'
gem 'sprockets', '2.12.1'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.8'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '2.13.1'
end

group :test do
  gem 'selenium-webdriver', '2.35.1'
  gem 'capybara', '2.1.0'
end

gem 'sass-rails', '4.0.1'
gem 'uglifier', '2.1.1'
gem 'coffee-rails', '4.0.1'
gem 'jquery-rails', '3.0.4'
gem 'turbolinks', '1.1.1'
gem 'jbuilder', '1.0.2'

group :doc do
  gem 'sdoc', '0.3.20', require: false
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg', '0.15.1'
  gem 'rails_12factor', '0.0.2'
end
```

I have looked at a lot of other posts on how to resolve similar issues, but to no avail.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: You should probably upgrade the gem version for [Bootstrap 3](http://getbootstrap.com/). `gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.2.0'`. Run bundle install, and *restart* your rails server once finished.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, unfortunately this didn't yield a different result

Comment: Is there a way where I can check to see that the gem file is being used by my application?

Comment: Have you run through the github repository installation instructions? [https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass)  With Rails 3.1+, you do already have sass-rails so that's ok, but have you added `@import "bootstrap-sprockets";` to your application.css file and `//= require jquery` & `//= require bootstrap-sprockets` to your application.js file? Also, have you restarted your rails server since adding code to your .css or .js files?

Comment: @cjn that's the solution add it as an answer. i mean, restarting the server

Comment: @Nicola Peluchetti Thanks for the status update!

Comment: @JustinLicata Your solution worked perfectly for me, even after trying the github solutions yours just worked.  They must have integrated the fix in that release.

Answer (score 2):

Having spent the better part of a day figuring out this issue, I thought I'd share my solution.  I too am following the Rails Tutorial by Hartl, and am following his advice by running everything in a cloud9 account.

The answer for me was to restart the server, however, this was not as easy as a simple ctrl+c as I had closed my terminal windows down entirely.  As a result, I tried to issue "rails server -b $IP -p $PORT", however, I received a `bind': Address already in use .. ' error.

So here's how I solved it:

From terminal:

1.) $ lsof -i :8080 -> output will show PID of process occupying port 8080: "httpd  1234  ....'

2.) $ kill -9 1234

All errors gone and bootstrap working properly!

Lastly (and most importantly), it should be noted that during the tutorials, you should always issue "rails server -b $IP -p $PORT" and not "rails server".  This is key.

Answer (score 1):

The same issue occurred for me too, while i have gone through the tutorial of Michael Hartl(https://www.railstutorial.org/book/). But after i give bundle command by changing the order of gems in the gem file, this issue solved. The above issue on my guess, is mainly due to the c9 editor not refreshed properly with installed gem.

Answer (score 1):

For me the solution was rename stylesheet file from css to scss

```
mv app/assets/stylesheets/application.css app/assets/stylesheets/application.scss
```

hope it help

Answer (score 0):

For the formal answer that sounds like it worked...

Have you run through the github repository installation instructions? https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass With Rails 3.1+, you do already have sass-rails so that's ok, but have you added @import `"bootstrap-sprockets";` to your application.css file and `//= require jquery` & `//= require bootstrap-sprockets` to your application.js file?

Also, have you restarted your rails server since adding code to your .css or .js files?

Comment: I have done this, and it still isn't working, I am getting the error:      Static pages Home page should have the content 'Sample App'
     Failure/Error: visit '/static_pages/home'
     ActionView::Template::Error:
       couldn't find file 'jquery'
         (in /Users/me/rails_projects/sample_app/app/assets/javascripts/application.js:13)
     # ./app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:7:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb__1639650066512045899_2207712920'
     # ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:8:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

Comment: It would be useful to see the lines of code around where it's flagging (javascripts/application.js:13 and appliction.html.erb:7). You have the jquery-rails gem outside a group, so that looks fine. In the mean time, I've seen gem versions not play well & an update in a gem was needed. Worst case, you might consider updating a version of jquery-rails with a newer one - [here's some options](https://rubygems.org/gems/jquery-rails)... or rspec-rails with a newer one - [more options](https://rubygems.org/gems/rspec-rails). Come to think of it, rspec-rails v2.13.1 gave me some issues in the past.

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing the Rails Tutorials and developing in cloud (c9), you should restart the workspace server. After that execute the rails test again and it will work.